# Django: How to retrieve last record in a reverse foreign key

Tags: django, foreign-keys, models

Models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
   name = ....

class Registration(models.Model):
   person  = models.ForeignKey(person)
   expires = models.DateField()
```

each year a new registration record is created.

now I want to find all of the persons whose registration has expired or who have never registered. Something like

```
Person.objects.filter(registration__expires__lte=date.today() )
```

but of course 'registration' can't be used in the query set against person.

Do I need to store the latest registration date in the person object? Or do I do the query against the registration table first? How do I find the persons with no registrations then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the persons with no registrations, you can annotate your person query with the registration count then filter on the annotated field:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Person.objects.annotate(reg_count=Count('registration')).filter(reg_count=0)
```

See the Django docs on annotate:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Answer (score 0):

I think you want select_related https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

```
person.objects.select_related('registration').filter(registration__expires__lte=date.today() )
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem for the user that has two registrations, one that has expired and one that has not. I need to find all users who either have no registrations (the answer below works there) or ONLY have registrations that have expired.